# availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes Missing in Xcode 12 beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, beta

I get the following snippet:

```
let newPhotoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: OSType(self.photoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!), processedFormat: nil)
```

When I build in Xcode 12 beta 6, I get the following error:

```
Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member 'availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes'
```

When I check the API documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput)), it does not show `availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`  as deprecated.

Anyone else has this issue?

### UPDATE

The above errors are only present when I try to render SwiftUI preview for Home Screen Widget. If I run the project normally, it runs perfectly fine without errors.

Also, I am getting same error for preview pixel types:

```
photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes[0]]

Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoSettings' has no member 'availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is now split into two queries:

Use `availableRawPhotoFileTypes` to get the supported RAW file types, choose one of them, and then ask for the corresponding supported format types with `supportedRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes(for fileType: AVFileType)`.

I think right now only DNG files are supported in iOS, but separating the APIs is probably more future-proof.

Comment: That seemed to work! However, for preview pixel types, there is no such method. (Please see my updated OP). Any idea?

Comment: This is strange... The method is only marked as unavailable in macOS. You are running on iOS, right?

Comment: I’m running iOS

Comment: It appears to happen when you build for iOS simulator (which is the case with SwiftUI previews).
Maybe `@available` logic was updated somehow.
I see the same with `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces`. It is marked as `@available(macOS 11.0, iOS 10.0, macCatalyst 14.0, *)`.

Comment: Very strange. I wonder if this is because a lot of the capture APIs are not available in the Simulator since it doesn't simulate a camera...

Comment: Can you point me to a fully working example on how capture RAW? I've found just chunk of codes that lead me to nothing.